# Error in Xcode 7 related to the core data saving concept

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The error :

> Cannot convert value of type 'inout NSError?' (aka 'inout
>   Optional') to expected argument type '()'

Code :

```
var error: NSError?
    if !managedContext.save(&error)
    {
        print("could not fetch data \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
```

Comment: try this  `do {
           try !managedContext.save()
         }
         catch let error as NSError{
               print("could not fetch data (error), (error!.userInfo)")
         }`

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! but the app will be crash after applying this code

Comment: what is error log ???